# Finance Questions : Credit Card interest

Tags: finance

Working through some problems on personal finance and this is the only set of questions I seem to not get a grasp on. I feel kind of like an idiot though for not being able to understand what to do. The payment due date being on December 8th is throwing me off. Could anyone help me with these questions? There are similar ones like these I will try on my own once I understand these. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The December 8 date does not matter at all.  The bill is for November.  You need to calculate the $P$ to be used according to each method, then apply the interest rate to that $P$.